# Script to find and replace cell background colours across a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a template sheet that I can quickly customise before sending out. One of these customisations is changing the heading and subheading cell background colours across multiple tabs in a sheet.
IE: on my copy of the sheet these headings are a light and dark yellow, I'd like to quickly change them to a light/dark blue etc without having to individually change each cell manually.

Ideally I would like a script to search current cell hex codes across the whole sheet, and if it encounters the current colour, change it to a new colour hex code.

I cant use conditional formatting for this as the text in these headers will differ, as well as their location on each tab.

Comment: Related solution by Martin Hawksey: [Batch changing Google Sheet cell background colours with Google Apps Script](https://hawksey.info/blog/2015/06/batch-changing-google-sheet-cell-background-colours/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an adaptation of the [Martin Hawksey](https://hawksey.info/blog/2015/06/batch-changing-google-sheet-cell-background-colours/) solution from 2015.

I've used `getMaxRows` and `getMaxColumns` (as opposed to `getLastRow`/`getLastColumn' or even` getDataRange`) to define the range because it isn't clear whether there might be cells that don't yet contain data but which have had their background changed.

Though this script doesn't use the more advanced methods such as `MAP`, it is still very fast.

---

```
function colorReplace() {
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 let sheets = ss.getSheets()
  
 // iterate across sheets, row 
 for (let s = 0;s<sheets.length;s++){
  var sheet = sheets[s]
  var cells = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds();
  var rows = cells.length;
  var cols = cells[0].length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
   for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
    if (cells[i][j] == '#fff2cc'){ // first color to change
     cells[i][j] = '#cfe2f3'; // first color change to
    } else if (cells[i][j] == '#f1c232'){ // second color to change
     cells[i][j] = '#3d85c6'; // second color to change
    }
   }
  }
  // update backgound colours
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).setBackgrounds(cells);
  Logger.log("sheet#="+s+", name: "+sheet.getName())
 }
}
```

Comment: My version is probably a lot slower but it first reads all of the colors on each selected sheet and then I post them into a dialog where the user and enter the replacements as required  The it continues to run making replacements in the data arrays and use one setBackgrounds for every sheet selected to change the color.  When complete the dialog closes.  It was a fun project.

Comment: @Cooper `It was a fun project` What better reason does one need for anything that one does here!

Comment: This worked flawlessly!

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Find and Replace Backgroundcolors on selected sheets**

This function takes a while to run because it's currently setup to look for background for every cell in each sheet you have selected.

When you run the function changeColorsInSelectedSheets() a dialog will appear after locating all of the colors on the selected sheets which may take a while and it will return with sheetnames and colors that have been located.  If you wish to replace any of these colors then put your replacement color into column 3 in the form of #ffffff or whatever color you pick.  It will not except names of colors and the # must be included. It will fail if your replacement is not 7 characters in length. Then press the save changes button and it will make the replacements and when it has completed the dialog will be removed.

GS:

```
function changeColorsInSelectedSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const incl = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"];
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => ~incl.indexOf(sh.getName()));
  let html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"><style>tr,td{border:1px solid black;}table{table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}</style></head><body><table id="clrtbl"><tbody><tr><th>Sheet Name</th><th>Current Color</th><th>New Color</th><th></th>`;
  let clrObj = { pA: [] };
  shts.forEach(sh => {
    let n = sh.getName();
    let cs = [... new Set(sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getMaxRows(), sh.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds().flat())];
    clrObj[n] = cs.slice();
    clrObj.pA.push(n);
  });
  let r = 0;
  clrObj.pA.forEach(p => {
    clrObj[p].forEach(e => {
      let c = 0;
      html += `<tr class="clr"><td id="clr-${r}-${c++}">${p}</td><td id="clr-${r}-${c++}">${e}</td><td contenteditable="true" id="clr-${r}-${c}"></td></tr>`;
      r++;
    });
  });
  html += '</tbody></table><br><input type="button" value="Save Changes" onClick="saveChanges();"/>';
  html += '<script>function saveChanges() {var arr = [];var r = document.getElementsByClassName("clr").length;for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {var j = 0;try {var sh = document.getElementById("clr-" + i + "-" + j++).innerHTML;var cu = document.getElementById("clr-" + i + "-" + j++).innerHTML;var ch = document.getElementById("clr-" + i + "-" + j++).innerHTML;arr.push([sh, cu, ch]);}catch(e) {console.log(e);console.log("r: %s j: %s",r,j);}}console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {google.script.host.close()}).changeMyColors(arr);}</script>';
  html += `</body></html>`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Color Dialog");
}

function changeMyColors(vs) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cObj = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    if (r[2].toString().includes("#") && r[2].toString().trim().length == 7) {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
        a[r[0]] = [{ current: r[1], replacement: r[2] }];
        a.pA.push(r[0]);
      } else {
        a[r[0]].push({ current: r[1], replacement: r[2] });
      }
    }
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(cObj));
  cObj.pA.forEach(p => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(p);
    let rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getMaxRows(), sh.getMaxColumns());
    let bs = rg.getBackgrounds();
    let cA = cObj[p].map(obj => obj.current);
    let rA = cObj[p].map(obj => obj.replacement);
    let o = bs.map((r, i) => {
      return r.map((c, j) => {
        let idx = cA.indexOf(c);
        if (~idx) {
          return cObj[p][idx].replacement;
        } else {
          return c;
        }
      });
    });
    rg.setBackgrounds(o);
  })
  return true;
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: That was a fun project for today. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will give this script a go as well!
I must admit scripts are an alien language to me haha!